# what does it mean that the effective receptive field to be large for Region Proposal Network in Faster R-CNN?

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, computer-vision, object-detection

I am trying to understand the Region Proposal Network portion (RPN) of the [faster R-CNN](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.01497) paper. Under section 3.1, the authors mention the justification for using a 3x3 sliding network over the convolutional feature map as having a large receptive field on the original image.

> We use n = 3 in this paper, noting that the effective receptive field on the input image is large (171 and 228 pixels for ZF and VGG, respectively).

What does having a large receptive field mean when the feature map is smaller than the original image?

Also, I am unsure about what this statement means.

> Note that because the mini-network operates in a sliding-window fashion, the fully-connected layers are shared across all spatial locations.

I am not sure about the stride used for the sliding window. However, there would not be overlap over the whole feature map. Eg. If I have feature map of 8x8 and convolutional filter of 3x3, certainly the lower parts of the feature map will not share overlap with the higher parts of the feature map.